Pull all values from multiple nested lists within a dictionary
Look at this dictionary:
{
    "0": {
        "server": 681262466650734596,
        "channel": 693639674841006101,
        "balance": 1000,
        "bal2": 30000,
        "regd": [
            {
                "user": 624748908479905812,
                "exp": 2015.0,
                "rank": 2,
                "points": 125.69999999999996,
                "msgs": 9999,
                "tokens": 10000
            },
            {
                "user": 1096531392369807492,
                "exp": 501.0,
                "rank": 1,
                "points": 1.4000000000000004,
                "msgs": 1,
                "tokens": 10000
            },
            {
                "user": 603657446233210908,
                "exp": 600,
                "rank": 2,
                "points": 169,
                "msgs": 0,
                "tokens": 12000
            },
            {
                "user": 248793436293955584,
                "exp": 630,
                "rank": 2,
                "points": 169,
                "msgs": 0,
                "tokens": 12000
            },
            {
                "user": 217098431393431553,
                "exp": 555,
                "rank": 2,
                "points": 169,
                "msgs": 0,
                "tokens": 12000
            }
        ]
    }
}

I am trying to write a function (with parameter: server number) that will iterate through this dictionary, find the dictionary with matching server number, and then iterate through the 'regd' key/values and return all 'exp' values.
So for example,
e = 'exp'
search_dictionary(serverNum, e)

The search_dictionary function is incomplete, not sure how to proceed, but the desired output is each of the exp values in a list, like this for instance: [2015.0, 501.0, 600, 630, 555]
I have this function currently but it does not work:
def PBX(self, User: int, Server: int):
        dop = self.ReadLevel()
        for key, value_key in dop.items():
            if value_key['server'] == Server:
                nd = value_key['regd']
                for key, value in nd.items():
                    if 'exp' in key:
                        res = []
                        res.append(value['exp'])
                        print(res)
                    return

Can someone help me out? I've done this before very similarly, yesterday I decided to revamp the dictionary style, still figuring out how to extract data with the new style
I made another function, but I still get nothing, nothing prints
def PBX(self, User: int, Server: int):
        dop = self.ReadLevel()
        for key, value_key in dop.items():
            if value_key['server'] == Server:
                nd = value_key['regd']
                res = []  # Initialize list to store 'exp' values
                for value_key in nd:
                    exp_value = value_key['exp']  # Get 'exp' value from user data
                    if exp_value is not None:  # Check if 'exp' key exists
                        res.append(exp_value)  # Append 'exp' value to result list
                        return print(res)  # Return the list of 'exp' values
        return []  # Return an empty list if server number not found

What am I missing here?

You can do something like this:

def get_exps(dct, server_num):
    out = []

    for d in dct.values():
        if d["server"] == server_num:
            for i in d["regd"]:
                out.append(i["exp"])
            break

    return out

dct = ... # your dictionary from the question

print(get_exps(dct, 681262466650734596))

Prints:
[2015.0, 501.0, 600, 630, 555]

If server number is not found, empty list is returned.

Possible reasons:

nd is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself.
code returns the result after only processing the first item in the list nd.
If you want to print all exp values the print statement should be outside the loop.

Try this:
def PBX(self, User: int, Server: int):
    dop = self.ReadLevel()  # ReadLevel returns the dictionary?! 
    for key, value_key in dop.items():
        if value_key['server'] == Server:  
            nd = value_key['regd']  # Get the 'regd' list! of dictionaries
            res = []  
            for user_data in nd:
                exp_value = user_data['exp']  # Get 'exp' value
                if exp_value is not None:  
                    res.append(exp_value)  
            return res  # Return list of 'exp' values
    return []  

